# unable to install apache superset ubuntu 18.04 or even ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualbox, apache-superset

I have been trying to install apache superset in ubuntu (both 18.04 and 16.04 -- inside virtualbox )

I am following their documentation at - https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#python-virtualenv but getting stuck.

Here are the steps I followed
Step 1

```
`sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3.5-dev python-pip libsasl2-dev` libldap2-dev
```

Step 2 :

```
pip install virtualenv
```

step 3 :

```
virtualenv venv
. ./venv/bin/activate
```

step 4 :

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

step 5 : 
pip install superset

and this is the step where I am getting stuck
and for ubuntu 18.04

the error message is something like this

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Sorry, Python < 3.6 is not supported

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-_atmAP/superset/
```

I am getting almost the exact same error with the only different being the error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-_atmAP/superset/

where it is some other letters instead of _atmAP in the above error code

So, could you guys tell me where am I going wrong with this?? and how to get it installed?

I have python 3.6.7 installed, but I think somehow python 2.7 is being used for this when I do `pip install superset`

take a look at this and maybe you'll get some idea

```
 pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (40.6.2)
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (18.1)
(venv) faraz@faraz-VirtualBox:~$ pip install superset
Collecting superset
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/48/583551048b9e045eed47dbd93c3210fa1e02193e4fad226033a19754525c/superset-0.28.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Sorry, Python < 3.6 is not supported

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-jNXS9r/superset/
(venv) faraz@faraz-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3.6-dev is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
(venv) faraz@faraz-VirtualBox:~$ pip install superset
Collecting superset
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/48/583551048b9e045eed47dbd93c3210fa1e02193e4fad226033a19754525c/superset-0.28.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Sorry, Python < 3.6 is not supported

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-M2CmSQ/superset/
```

What do you think? 
how to fix this??

Comment: Read the error message: "Sorry, Python < 3.6 is not supported".

Comment: yeah. but I am using python 3.6.7. it is already installed. even checked it with python --version and I can see python 3.6.7

Comment: @KlausD. , I think you are right. I think that somehow python 2.7 is getting used instead of 3.6.7 when i do pip install superset.

I have pasted some more details in my original post. please take a look. it might give you some more idea of what's going on.

Comment: If you are using the system python and not a virtual environment then try using `python3` and `pip3` as commands.

Answer (score 2):

Could you create a virtual environment using python3.6 :-

```
virtualenv -p python3.6 ENV
```

Activate your environment

```
source ENV/bin/activate
```

Then try to install superset using below command:-

```
ENV/bin/pip3.6 install superset
```

Answer (score 2):

following is working for me well in Ubuntu16.04:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.6 python3.6-dev
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
sudo pip3 install superset
```